# How to write protractor code to connect to mysql (Linux) db from Windows

Tags: protractor, database-connection

I have to connect to MySql db (Linux server) for some database validation. I am running the protractor code in Windows environment.

The code I am using is:

```
return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
    var config = {
        user: '****',
        password: '*****',
        server: '****',
        database: '***',

        options: {
            encrypt: true
        }
    };

    var connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    connection.connect(function (err) {
        reject(err);
        let query = "select * from **"
        connection.request().query(query, (err, recordeset) => {
            console.dir('Record set: ' + recordeset)
            console.dir('Err: ' + err)

            if (err) reject(err);
            else fulfill(recordeset);
        });
    });
});
```

The error is:

```
Failed: Failed to connect to <server name>:1433 in 15000ms
```

Comment: Please check your windows machine can access the mysql on linux server. you can install tool 'mysql workbench' on windows, then use it to connect your mysql to check the connection is go through.  mysql default start port is 3306, but from your error the port is 1433, did you start mysql on 1433 port. And check the firewall setting on linux server to enable TCP inbound and outbound traffic on the start port.

Comment: I tried to test the connection in workbench for port 1433 but that failed. I mentioned the "port : 3306' in the code itself and that is showing this error: "Failed: Failed to connect to <server name> in 15000ms"